# find length of an svg circle via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am looking to create a variable that will hold the svg circle length calculated in jquery.

```
$(function() {

  $('svg').hover(function() {
    /* Stuff to do when the mouse enters the element */

    var pathLen = $(this).find('circle').getLengthOfPath????

    $(this).find('circle')
      .stop()
      .animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': 0
      }, 1000, 'easOutBounce');
      console.log('on');
  }, function() {
    /* Stuff to do when the mouse leaves the element */
    $(this).find('circle')
      .stop()
      .animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': pathLen
      }, 1000, 'easOutBounce');
  });
});
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Step one: wonder "how do I do this", without jquery. (as you discovered). Then step two can always be "and can that be done more concisely if I use jQuery". Starting with "how do I do this in jquery" without the option that it might not even need it, risks never finding a decent solution (sometimes plain JS is far more efficient than jQuery, like in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The path length of a circle is 2 * pi * cr. There's no built in method to work this out.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your speedy response. but i am still having some issues. So using my example above, how would i implement that into my code as I am still receiving an error.

I have multiple SVG elements with a circle element in it.

Comment: What error?  If you want a more detailed response, post a working example that shows the problem.  Add a snippet to your question, or use a service like jsfiddle.

Comment: The getTotalLength() function is defined on SVGPathElement but not on SVGCircleElement. Calling getTotalLength() function will work on <path> elements but will throw error on <circle> elements.

Comment: sorry, was being stupid for a second figured it out.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: remember that if you do use a real `<circle>` element, this answer is almost, but not quite, correct: it's a value between 2·π·(cr - strokeweight/2) and 2·π·(cr + strokeweight/2), as there are now at least three possible "circumferences": inner circumference at the circle/stroke edge, "true" circumference if we ignore stroke, and outer circumference at the stroke/canvas edge.

Comment: getTotalLength() on a path will return the "true" length so the code above is consistent with that.